# QGIS write in attribute table while mouse clicking

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, print-composer

I want to draw a track in QGIS with mouse-click to use it inside the print composer(atlas generation).

The best way to do this for me is too click on the screen and the Python script in the background set an autoincrement on my first column in the attribute table of my layer.

I already use it with the "add feature" function in QGIS, but it's not really comfortable.

For each click I make, a new row should be created. Does someone have an idea how to program this task with PyQGIS?

Comment: Questions seeking help to debug/write/improve code must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Providing a clear problem statement and evidence of a code attempt will help others to help you.